# Hide Custom Fields in New Post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-fields

I just started out with WordPress and I'm having some problems with the custom fields. Here's the code from functions.php

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Post Thumbnail', $post_thumb, true) or update_post_meta($post_id, 'Post Thumbnail', $post_thumb);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Project URL', $url, true) or update_post_meta($post_id, 'Project URL', $url);
add_post_meta($post_id, 'Project Thumbnail', $thumb, true) or update_post_meta($post_id, 'Project Thumbnail', $thumb);
```

The problem is that they show up when I try to create a new post like so:

[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/118004/Screen%20shot%202010-05-12%20at%2010.45.35%20AM.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/118004/Screen%20shot%202010-05-12%20at%2010.45.35%20AM.png)

The other problem is that they don't even work, only if I publish the post, go back and readd each field. Is there any way to hide the fields to only show the "Add new custom field:" part? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following will help you create custom meta boxes:

http://farinspace.com/wordpress-meta-box-next-level/