# Updating bootstrap datepicker after initialization using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datepicker with the following custom KnockoutJS binding, which worked fine for me until now:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepicker || {};

    $(element).datepicker(options);

    //when a user changes the date, update the view model
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
        value(event.date);
      }                
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
    var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
    if (widget) {
      widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      widget.setValue();            
    }
  }
```

};

Now, I have a situation where I get the `startDate` and `endDate` values **after** the datepicker initialization takes place. I've set up an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6WR5r/

The datepicker is initialized with the correct dates, but when I hit the "Change Date" button, the datepicker is not updated, even though the `update` function on the custom binding is fired.

I've tried different versions of the `update` function, with no success:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor)   {
  var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepicker || {};
  $(element).datepicker(options);
}

update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor)   {
  $(element).datepicker('update');
}
```

The only thing that worked was using the `setStartDate` and `setEndDate` methods, like this:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
  var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepicker || {};

  $(element).datepicker('setStartDate', options.startDate);
  $(element).datepicker('setEndDate', options.endDate);
}
```

But I'm looking for a better approach. Is there a way to use the `update` function to update the datepicker with the new values, without having to specify which options to update?

Comment: You don't seem very [interested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816872/hide-custom-fields-in-new-post) in [following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208615/local-develop-branch-ahead-of-remote-develop-branch-by-17-commits) the [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082530/ignore-foreach-afteradd-and-beforeremove-in-certain-situations) you get...

Comment: The answers I've been getting lately were not helpful enough to mark them as accepted.

Comment: Maybe you can comment on them to explain how they are not useful to you. It feels like you ask and leave; it does not make people want to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in two questions you make me write two ugly solutions...

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269813/changing-startdate-and-enddate-params-of-bootstrap-datepicker-on-change-of-a-sel) you need to remove the plugin and re-create it when you want to change `startDate` or `endDate` :(

Your update function becomes:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    console.log("update fired");

     //when the view model is updated, update the widget
    if ($(element).data("datepicker")) {
        $(element).datepicker("remove");
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepicker || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);
        $(element).data("datepicker").date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).data("datepicker").setValue();            
    } 
}
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/6WR5r/2/)**

Comment: I'd rather have an ugly solution than no solution :) This is great. Thanks for the quick response! One more question. If the `update` function always fires after `init`, is there a point to keep datepicker initialization code (`var options =` ... `$(element).datepicker(options);` ) in both functions?

Comment: Indeed you could handle the datepicker creation in the `update` function here. The [doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) says (like you) the `update` function is called on init too.